# What do the Secret Seashells do?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

In Link's Awakening, sometimes I come across Secret Seashells, and the text that pops up says that if I collect a lot of them, something good is bound to happen.

what will happen if I collect enough? (How many is enough, anyhow?)

Comment: btw, [here](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda04-links-awakening-secret-seashells.php)'s a guide to all 26 shells

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be brought to the Seashell Mansion at various points to earn things.

- 5 shells gets you a bonus shell.
- 10 shells gets you another bonus shell.
- 20+ shells gets you the Level-2 Sword, capable of shooting beams at full health (as well as being more powerful in general).

There are several extra hidden around the island (about a total of 25). After you've cashed in 20 of them, any extra ones in chests you haven't opened will turn into 20 rupees.

(Bonus fun fact: you can put bombs in the wooden wall at the end of the Mansion's insides. For some reason, they fall into it!)

Answer (score 1):

If you collect and bring 20 of them to the Seashell house, you'll get a more powerful sword. There should be a bit more than 20 in total, so you don't have to find all of them.

Comment: I think there are at least 21, 22 at the most.